# Why does "Additional Drivers" Fail?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, broadcom

When trying to Activate, Broadcom B43legacy wireless driver I get the following error,

```
SystemError: installArchives() failed.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I've found these bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/626320
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/658106

You can install the driver manually by installing package `firmware-b43legacy-installer`

Comment: thank you!
I had to go to synaptic and totally remove the old firmware-b43legacy-installer, then re-download it to make it work, but I'm now on line wireless to post this comment  =)
many thanks
this is on a 12" powerbook g4 ppc chip

Answer (score 1):

I got this error as well when I ran Ubuntu from the install cd. Turns out the cd had an error on it. Just burned a new one and everything was ok ;) So if you're getting the error while running from the cd, you might want to try burning a new one!

Comment: Thanks, trying this on a full install not the CD. I also have read the bug reports and try installing through the terminal. Get another error: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
I noticed in 11.04 alpha that it is nit even offered in Additional Drivers. May it is no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).

```
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 2.6.38-13-generic #57~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 6 19:39:06 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Looking around they recommended installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` but that didn't help, as at some point it failed to install (didn't found *linux/autoconf.h*).

The solution was to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `bcmwl-modaliases` from the deb package. You can download the deb package for i386 architecture from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/5.60.48.36+bdcom-0ubuntu5/+build/1781446/).